# Swift: fill data into unsafeMutablePointer of UInt8 type doesn't work

Tags: swift

I have the following code which doesn't work. How can I fill in data into the memory block of `UnsafeMutablePointer`? The bufferSize is 1024. I tried to fill 0, 1, 2...1023 into the buffer.

```
let pbuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(bufferSize)

for index in 0...bufferSize - 1 
{

    pbuffer[index] = UInt8(index)

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: FYI, you can use the [Half-Open Range Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_128) instead of `bufferSize - 1` in that for loop: `for index in 0..<bufferSize`

Comment: What about that code doesn't work for you? What are your expected results and what are the results that you are getting?

Comment: Thank you! It keeps on stopping at the close bracket " } " and show this message: "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe". I don't have any break point at all. If I change bufferSize - 1 to 10, this code block can pass. I want to fill in data 1, 2, 3...1024 in the pbuff for my test application.

Comment: Perfect. The fact that you're using a `bufferSize` of `1024` is critical to solving this question. Can you edit your question and add that info so that it's easily visible to others?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is not the `UnsafeMutablePointer`, but rather that you're trying to initialize a `UInt8` with a value that won't fit in it; `UInt8` has a maximum value of `255`. So, up to a `bufferSize` of `256`, your code will work fine; beyond that, it'll crash.

All you need to do to fix this is use a different type for your `UnsafeMutablePointer`. If you want to go up to a `bufferSize` of `1024`, a `UInt16` will work fine (max value `65535`):

```
let bufferSize = 1024
let pbuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>.alloc(bufferSize)

for index in 0..<bufferSize
{
    pbuffer[index] = UInt16(index)
}
```